# Setting a textchanged event to only fire when text is actually entered by user not program

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Windows forms Application. VB .NET 4.0 In my application I have a global boolean variable that  keeps track of when changes are made and when they are saved called changesSaved. On closing even it checks the value of this variable before closing the window.. I am using textchanged event to automatically change the value of changesSaved to FALSE when text is changed.. Problem: The group box items are being populated dynamically so the user can edit the values or simply just view them. This dynamic population is causing the textchanged event to fire because the program is changing the text value of the box to put the values in that are stored in the database. The textchanged event should not fire unless the user him or herself enters a value or values in the text boxes.. Is there a way to specify the source i guess you could say for the text changed event or another way so that it will only fire when the user inputs information.??? Functions are as follows: The first is called by the load event to place the values in the box... The next one is the one that is being called as a result of the first one and is also the one that is causing the problems..

```
Private Sub loadProperty(ByVal x As Integer)
    Dim _property As property_info = db.property_info.Single(Function(s) s.idProperties = x)
    p_settingsCity.Text = _property.city.ToString
    p_settingsState.Text = _property.state.ToString
    p_settings_PropertyName.Text = _property.property_Name.ToString
    p_settingsZipCode.Text = _property.zipcode.ToString
    p_settings_Address.Text = _property.address1.ToString
    p_settingsCity.Text = _property.city.ToString
    p_settingsState.Text = _property.state.ToString
        If _property.AllowRentProration = 1 Then
          RentProrate.Checked = True
        Else
          RentProrate.Checked = False
        End If
    RentProrate.Visible = True
End Sub


Private Sub PropertyTextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PropertyDetailsGroup.TextChanged
    ChangesSaved = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe just move the ChangesSaved = False statement to your KeyUp event.  Then it knows when the user has typed something as opposed to the program changing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple different ways.

Since you are just doing `ChangesSaved = False` in the `TextChanged` event, just set it to `True` *after* you programmatically update it.

```
Private Sub loadProperty(ByVal x As Integer)
  '// code
  RentProrate.Visible = True
  ChangesSaved = True
End Sub
```

---

Or just remove the `TextChanged` handler, update the TextBox programmatically, then add the handler back in.

```
RemoveHandler PropertyDetailsGroup.TextChanged, AddressOf PropertyTextChanged
PropertyDetailsGroup.Text = "value from database"
AddHandler PropertyDetailsGroup.TextChanged, AddressOf PropertyTextChanged
```

---

Implementing an *INotiftyPropertyChanged* interface and using `Databinding` would be another way, cleaner actually.  You wouldn't need the flag at the form level, you could catch any changes made by the user at the Class level, something like this:

```
Public Class TestClass
  Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

  Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

  Private _IsDirty As Boolean = False
  Private _TextValue As String = String.Empty

  Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
    _IsDirty = True
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
  End Sub

  Public ReadOnly Property IsDirty() As Boolean
    Get
      Return _IsDirty
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Property TextValue() As String
    Get
      Return _TextValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      If value <> _TextValue Then
        _TextValue = value
        OnPropertyChanged("TextValue")
      End If
    End Set
  End Property

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks again... Your solution addresses some other issues as well that I would've ran into.. Thanks for all the suggestion I decided against the keyup event because if the user uses the tab key alone on the window that would trip the changesSaved = False...

Comment: @Skindeep2366 Not to mention using the mouse to right-click and pasting text.  No keyboard event there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `Validated()` instead of the `TextChanged` Event. `Validated()` is only called when the focus of said element gets changed by user input. That way you're save to populate your `TextBox`'es by an external source.

[Control.Validated Event @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.CONTROL.VALIDATED%29;k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.TEXTBOX%29;k%28VS.PROPERTIES%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true)